# consul: increased the replicaset but new pods are not starting and getting Init:CrashLoopBackOff, how to fix that?

Tags: kubernetes, consul, eks

With single replicaset, the application is working.
So I changed the replicaset to 3.

Then, the other two copies of pods are not starting.:
kubectl get pods

```
 customservice-c8645cd6-7gghm                                   0/3     Init:CrashLoopBackOff   8          17m
    customservice-c8645cd6-f5nbn                                   3/3     Running                 0          6h50m
    customservice-c8645cd6-fh57n                                   0/3     Init:CrashLoopBackOff   8          17m


 kubectl describe pod customservice-c8645cd6-fh57n  

 Name:         customservice-c8645cd6-7gghm
Namespace:    default
Priority:     0
Node:         ip-192-168-93-234.us-west-2.compute.internal/192.168.93.234
Start Time:   Tue, 20 Jul 2021 19:34:48 +0530
Labels:       app=customservice
              consul.hashicorp.com/connect-inject-status=injected
              pod-template-hash=c8645cd6
              service=customservice
Annotations:  consul.hashicorp.com/connect-inject: true
              consul.hashicorp.com/connect-inject-status: injected
              consul.hashicorp.com/connect-service: customservice
              consul.hashicorp.com/connect-service-port: 18170
              consul.hashicorp.com/connect-service-upstreams: dashboard:9002
              kubernetes.io/psp: eks.privileged
              prometheus.io/path: /metrics
              prometheus.io/port: 20200
              prometheus.io/scrape: true
Status:       Pending
IP:           192.168.93.88
IPs:
  IP:           192.168.93.88
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/customservice-c8645cd6
Init Containers:
  consul-connect-inject-init:
    Container ID:  docker://a9bf6bb490f5c21637c18aff681d49d53692f09a3333bf34adb2080816953e26
    Image:         hashicorp/consul:1.9.7
    Image ID:      docker-pullable://hashicorp/consul@sha256:37c7a001af46a68f8e3513bd8180e7f84133d428b0e4ce5cf385d3e54f894760
    Port:          <none>
    Host Port:     <none>
    Command:
      /bin/sh
      -ec

      export CONSUL_HTTP_ADDR="${HOST_IP}:8500"
      export CONSUL_GRPC_ADDR="${HOST_IP}:8502"

      # Register the service. The HCL is stored in the volume so that
      # the preStop hook can access it to deregister the service.
      cat <<EOF >/consul/connect-inject/service.hcl
      services {
        id   = "${SERVICE_ID}"
        name = "customservice"
        address = "${POD_IP}"
        port = 18170
        meta = {
          pod-name = "${POD_NAME}"
          k8s-namespace = "${POD_NAMESPACE}"
        }
      }

      services {
        id   = "${PROXY_SERVICE_ID}"
        name = "customservice-sidecar-proxy"
        kind = "connect-proxy"
        address = "${POD_IP}"
        port = 20000
        meta = {
          pod-name = "${POD_NAME}"
          k8s-namespace = "${POD_NAMESPACE}"
        }

        proxy {
        config {
          envoy_prometheus_bind_addr = "0.0.0.0:20200"
        }
          destination_service_name = "customservice"
          destination_service_id = "${SERVICE_ID}"
          local_service_address = "127.0.0.1"
          local_service_port = 18170
          upstreams {
            destination_type = "service"
            destination_name = "dashboard"
            local_bind_port = 9002
          }
        }

        checks {
          name = "Proxy Public Listener"
          tcp = "${POD_IP}:20000"
          interval = "10s"
          deregister_critical_service_after = "10m"
        }

        checks {
          name = "Destination Alias"
          alias_service = "${SERVICE_ID}"
        }
      }
      EOF

      /bin/consul services register \
        /consul/connect-inject/service.hcl

      # Generate the envoy bootstrap code
      /bin/consul connect envoy \
        -proxy-id="${PROXY_SERVICE_ID}" \
        -prometheus-scrape-path="/metrics" \
        -prometheus-backend-port="20100" \
        -bootstrap > /consul/connect-inject/envoy-bootstrap.yaml

      # Copy the Consul binary
      cp /bin/consul /consul/connect-inject/consul
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       CrashLoopBackOff
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Error
      Exit Code:    1
      Started:      Tue, 20 Jul 2021 19:51:19 +0530
      Finished:     Tue, 20 Jul 2021 19:51:23 +0530
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  8
    Limits:
      cpu:     50m
      memory:  150Mi
    Requests:
      cpu:     50m
      memory:  25Mi
    Environment:
      HOST_IP:            (v1:status.hostIP)
      POD_IP:             (v1:status.podIP)
      POD_NAME:          customservice-c8645cd6-7gghm (v1:metadata.name)
      POD_NAMESPACE:     default (v1:metadata.namespace)
      SERVICE_ID:        $(POD_NAME)-customservice
      PROXY_SERVICE_ID:  $(POD_NAME)-customservice-sidecar-proxy
    Mounts:
      /consul/connect-inject from consul-connect-inject-data (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from customservice-token-4xf6t (ro)
Containers:
  customservice:
    Container ID:
    Image:          customserverlinux.azurecr.io/custom:latest
    Image ID:
    Port:           18170/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       PodInitializing
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment:
      DASHBOARD_CONNECT_SERVICE_HOST:  127.0.0.1
      DASHBOARD_CONNECT_SERVICE_PORT:  9002
    Mounts:
      /home/spring/AppData/Local/erwin/custom Server/ from custom-volume (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from customservice-token-4xf6t (ro)
  envoy-sidecar:
    Container ID:
    Image:         envoyproxy/envoy-alpine:v1.16.0
    Image ID:
    Port:          <none>
    Host Port:     <none>
    Command:
      envoy
      --config-path
      /consul/connect-inject/envoy-bootstrap.yaml
      -l
      debug
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       PodInitializing
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment:
      HOST_IP:            (v1:status.hostIP)
      CONSUL_HTTP_ADDR:  $(HOST_IP):8500
    Mounts:
      /consul/connect-inject from consul-connect-inject-data (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from customservice-token-4xf6t (ro)
  consul-sidecar:
    Container ID:
    Image:         hashicorp/consul-k8s:0.25.0
    Image ID:
    Port:          <none>
    Host Port:     <none>
    Command:
      consul-k8s
      consul-sidecar
      -service-config
      /consul/connect-inject/service.hcl
      -consul-binary
      /consul/connect-inject/consul
      -enable-metrics-merging=true
      -merged-metrics-port=20100
      -service-metrics-port=18170
      -service-metrics-path=/metrics
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       PodInitializing
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  0
    Limits:
      cpu:     20m
      memory:  50Mi
    Requests:
      cpu:     20m
      memory:  25Mi
    Environment:
      HOST_IP:            (v1:status.hostIP)
      CONSUL_HTTP_ADDR:  $(HOST_IP):8500
    Mounts:
      /consul/connect-inject from consul-connect-inject-data (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from customservice-token-4xf6t (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       False
  Ready             False
  ContainersReady   False
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  custom-volume:
    Type:       EmptyDir (a temporary directory that shares a pod's lifetime)
    Medium:
    SizeLimit:  <unset>
  customservice-token-4xf6t:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  customservice-token-4xf6t
    Optional:    false
  consul-connect-inject-data:
    Type:        EmptyDir (a temporary directory that shares a pod's lifetime)
    Medium:
    SizeLimit:   <unset>
QoS Class:       Burstable
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                   From               Message
  ----     ------     ----                  ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  19m                   default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/customservice-c8645cd6-7gghm to ip-192-168-93-234.us-west-2.compute.internal
  Normal   Pulled     17m (x5 over 19m)     kubelet            Container image "hashicorp/consul:1.9.7" already present on machine
  Normal   Created    17m (x5 over 19m)     kubelet            Created container consul-connect-inject-init
  Normal   Started    17m (x5 over 19m)     kubelet            Started container consul-connect-inject-init
  Warning  BackOff    3m50s (x68 over 18m)  kubelet            Back-off restarting failed container
```

As the init container is failing,logs for that container:

kubectl logs customservice-c8645cd6-64j2j -c consul-connect-inject-init

```
Registered service: customservice
Registered service: customservice-sidecar-proxy
flag provided but not defined: -prometheus-scrape-path
Usage:
  -address value
        LAN address to advertise in the gateway service registration
  -admin-access-log-path string
        The path to write the access log for the administration server. If no access log is desired specify "/dev/null". By default it will use "/dev/null". (default "/dev/null")
  -admin-bind string
        The address:port to start envoy's admin server on. Envoy requires this but care must be taken to ensure it's not exposed to an untrusted network as it has full control over the secrets and config of the proxy. (default "localhost:19000")
  -bind-address <name>=<ip>:<port>
        Bind address to use instead of the default binding rules given as <name>=<ip>:<port> pairs. This flag may be specified multiple times to add multiple bind addresses.
  -bootstrap
        Generate the bootstrap.json but don't exec envoy
  -ca-file value
        Path to a CA file to use for TLS when communicating with Consul. This can also be specified via the CONSUL_CACERT environment variable.
  -ca-path value
        Path to a directory of CA certificates to use for TLS when communicating with Consul. This can also be specified via the CONSUL_CAPATH environment variable.
  -client-cert value
        Path to a client cert file to use for TLS when 'verify_incoming' is enabled. This can also be specified via the CONSUL_CLIENT_CERT environment variable.
  -client-key value
        Path to a client key file to use for TLS when 'verify_incoming' is enabled. This can also be specified via the CONSUL_CLIENT_KEY environment variable.
  -deregister-after-critical string
        The amount of time the gateway services health check can be failing before being deregistered (default "6h")
  -envoy-binary string
        The full path to the envoy binary to run. By default will just search $PATH. Ignored if -bootstrap is used.
  -envoy-version string
        Sets the envoy-version that the envoy binary has. (default "1.16.4")
  -expose-servers
        Expose the servers for WAN federation via this mesh gateway
  -gateway string
        The type of gateway to register. One of: terminating, ingress, or mesh
  -grpc-addr string
        Set the agent's gRPC address and port (in http(s)://host:port format). Alternatively, you can specify CONSUL_GRPC_ADDR in ENV. (default "192.168.93.234:8502")
  -http-addr address
        The address and port of the Consul HTTP agent. The value can be an IP address or DNS address, but it must also include the port. This can also be specified via the CONSUL_HTTP_ADDR environment variable. The default value is http://127.0.0.1:8500. The scheme can also be set to HTTPS by setting the environment variable CONSUL_HTTP_SSL=true.
  -mesh-gateway
        Configure Envoy as a Mesh Gateway.
  -namespace default
        Specifies the namespace to query. If not provided, the namespace will be inferred from the request's ACL token, or will default to the default namespace. Namespaces are a Consul Enterprise feature.
  -no-central-config
        By default the proxy's bootstrap configuration can be customized centrally. This requires that the command run on the same agent as the proxy will and that the agent is reachable when the command is run. In cases where either assumption is violated this flag will prevent the command attempting to resolve config from the local agent.
  -omit-deprecated-tags
        In Consul 1.9.0 the format of metric tags for Envoy clusters was updated from consul.[service|dc|...] to consul.destination.[service|dc|...]. The old tags were preserved for backward compatibility,but can be disabled with this flag.
  -proxy-id string
        The proxy's ID on the local agent.
  -register
        Register a new gateway service before configuring and starting Envoy
  -service string
        Service name to use for the registration
  -sidecar-for string
        The ID of a service instance on the local agent that this proxy should become a sidecar for. It requires that the proxy service is registered with the agent as a connect-proxy with Proxy.DestinationServiceID set to this value. If more than one such proxy is registered it will fail.
  -tls-server-name value
        The server name to use as the SNI host when connecting via TLS. This can also be specified via the CONSUL_TLS_SERVER_NAME environment variable.
  -token value
        ACL token to use in the request. This can also be specified via the CONSUL_HTTP_TOKEN environment variable. If unspecified, the query will default to the token of the Consul agent at the HTTP address.
  -token-file value
        File containing the ACL token to use in the request instead of one specified via the -token argument or CONSUL_HTTP_TOKEN environment variable. This can also be specified via the CONSUL_HTTP_TOKEN_FILE environment variable.
  -wan-address value
        WAN address to advertise in the gateway service registration. For ingress gateways, only an IP address (without a port) is required.
```

Any suggestion on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Im not a consul expert, however.. check [consul-connect-inject-init gets pods stuck in podInitialisation loop because of the -prometheus-scrape-path flag #919](https://githubmemory.com/repo/hashicorp/consul-helm/issues/919). The issue itself the same you have, behavior the same and error also the same. Maybe that information will help you

```
Registered service: customservice
Registered service: customservice-sidecar-proxy
flag provided but not defined: -prometheus-scrape-path
Usage:
```

```
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                   From               Message
  ----     ------     ----                  ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  19m                   default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/customservice-c8645cd6-7gghm to ip-192-168-93-234.us-west-2.compute.internal
  Normal   Pulled     17m (x5 over 19m)     kubelet            Container image "hashicorp/consul:1.9.7" already present on machine
  Normal   Created    17m (x5 over 19m)     kubelet            Created container consul-connect-inject-init
  Normal   Started    17m (x5 over 19m)     kubelet            Started container consul-connect-inject-init
  Warning  BackOff    3m50s (x68 over 18m)  kubelet            Back-off restarting failed container
```

---

What version do you have?

> in order to enable metrics merging of sidecar and application metrics
> (connectInject.metrics.defaultEnableMerging : true) you need to be
> using Consul 1.10.0-alpha1 or above. You can remove that value until
> you've upgraded Consul. You can still get just envoy metrics while
> using an older Consul version with
> connectInject.metrics.defaultEnabled: true.

MOre details: Consul helm annotation [connectinject-metrics-defaultenablemerging](https://www.consul.io/docs/k8s/helm#v-connectinject-metrics-defaultenablemerging)